# Конфигурация .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, сервер

Просмотрела уже много ресурсов на тему конфигурирования .htaccess под разные цели, остался один вопрос

как всё таки должен выглядеть работающий .htaccess файл?
как я поняла принцип такой -

```
<IfModule нужный_модуль>
Интересующие опции модуля
</IfModule>
```

но как же тогда должен выглядеть простой 301 редирект? Просто строчка типа

```
 Redirect 301 / http://yoursitename.ru/
```

или он должен быть включен в какой-либо модуль? Я вот этого понять не могу.
И нужно ли в конфигурации .htaccess указывать на модуль, если он подключен в самом конфиге апача?

Answer (score 1):

Проверку <ifmodule> делать надо, чтобы апач не вываливался с ошибками в случае чего.
Или для стандартизации и масштабируемости конфигураций (например, если у вас может быть подключено два разных модуля, а работать может только один из них). Поэтому основная часть может меняться, а дополнительные конфиги остаются неизменными.

Если мне не изменяет память, редирект подобного рода является частью стандартных функций апач-сервера.